# programmatically fetch LDAP User from LifeRay

Tags: liferay

I am new to LifeRay and trying to fetch user from LDAP programmatically inside liferay portlet.
Can any one let me know how to pass a userID to the LDAP server and get the corresponding user?
It would be really great if a sample program can be included here for reference.

regards,
Deepak.

Comment: Please post code which you have tried!

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

You need to specify your portal version and release (ex: 6.1 EE, 6.1 CE, 7.0 EE, DXP, etc) for accurate instruction.  It would also be helpful if you state your reason because very often in Liferay a new developer tries to solve a problem that has already been solved. Liferay 6.x ships with a portlet that allows you to manage LDAP / AD integration as well as robust properties configurations.  Your ability to get this to work with their programmatic API will depend also on your ability to configure the LDAP integration correctly.

### Configuration

Before successfully using the programmatic API I suggest you first configure LDAP integration via the portlet and/or the config files.  You can find the LDAP portlet doing the following:

1. Control Panel
2. Portal Settings
3. Authentication
4. LDAP

From there you will need to set your URI, ports, field maps, etc. Test your connection.

## Programmatic API

What you actually want to do is unknown so I'll give you what I believe are the most useful utilities.  Pseudo code would look something like

```
User user = null;
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay;

try {
    themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    user = PortalLDAPImporterUtil.importLDAPUser(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), "email", "screenanme");
    UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(user);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```